# how to resolve "warning: no model found for en_core_web_sm" even though i have downloaded the model and written a config file with it

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, spacy, rasa, spacy-3

[image: please diagnose this]

```
    config = """
    language: "en"
    pipeline:
      - name: "nlp_spacy"
        model: "en_core_web_sm"
      - name: "tokenizer_spacy"
      - name: "intent_entity_featurizer_regex"
      - name: "intent_featurizer_spacy"
      - name: "ner_crf"
      - name: "ner_synonyms"
      - name: "intent_classifier_sklearn"
      """


    with open('config.yml', 'a') as f:
            print(config, file = f)
    f.close()
```

[image: vscode]

```
    from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
    from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
    from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
    from rasa_nlu import config
    import spacy

    # Load training data
    training_data = load_data("intent.md")

    # Use trainer to load configuration data the needs to be learnt by the model
    trainer = Trainer(config.load("config.yml"))

    # Train model on training data
    interpreter = trainer.train(training_data)

    # Save Model
    model_directory = trainer.persist("./models/nlu")
```

Here is my conda list

```
(venv) (base) PS C:\Users\Vatsal\AgriculturalChatbot-master> conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Vatsal\anaconda3:
#**
```

```
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py36_0
    alabaster                 0.7.12                   py36_0
    anaconda                  2020.07                  py36_0
    anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py36_0
    anaconda-navigator        2.0.4                    py36_0
    anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0
    argh                      0.26.2                   py36_0
    asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py36_0
    astroid                   2.4.2                    py36_0
    astropy                   4.0.1.post1      py36he774522_1
    atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
    attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
    automat                   20.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    autopep8                  1.5.3                      py_0
    babel                     2.8.0                      py_0
    backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0
    backports                 1.0                        py_2
    backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0
    backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py36_2
    backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1
    backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
    bcrypt                    3.1.7            py36he774522_1
    beautifulsoup4            4.9.1                    py36_0
    bitarray                  1.4.0            py36he774522_0
    bkcharts                  0.2                      py36_0
    blas                      1.0                         mkl
    bleach                    3.1.5                      py_0
    blosc                     1.19.0               h7bd577a_0
    bokeh                     2.1.1                    py36_0
    boto                      2.49.0                   py36_0
    boto3                     1.18.16                  pypi_0    pypi
    botocore                  1.21.16                  pypi_0    pypi
    bottleneck                1.3.2            py36h2a96729_1
    brotlipy                  0.7.0           py36he774522_1000
    bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
    ca-certificates           2020.6.24                     0
    catalogue                 2.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
    certifi                   2020.6.20                py36_0
    cffi                      1.14.0           py36h7a1dbc1_0
    chardet                   3.0.4                 py36_1003
    click                     7.1.2                      py_0
    cloudpickle               0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
    clyent                    1.2.2                    py36_1
    colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
    coloredlogs               10.0                     pypi_0    pypi
    comtypes                  1.1.7                 py36_1001
    conda                     4.10.3           py36ha15d459_0    conda-forge
    conda-build               3.21.4           py36haa95532_0
    conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
    conda-env                 2.6.0                         1
    conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py36h8cc25b3_1
    conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
    conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
    conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
    console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
    constantly                15.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0
    contextvars               2.4                        py_0
    cryptography              2.9.2            py36h7a1dbc1_0
    curl                      7.71.1               h2a8f88b_1
    cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
    cymem                     2.0.5            py36he2d232f_2    conda-forge
    cython                    0.29.21          py36ha925a31_0
    cython-blis               0.7.4            py36h6434af4_0    conda-forge
    cytoolz                   0.10.1           py36he774522_0
    dask                      2.20.0                     py_0
    dask-core                 2.20.0                     py_0
    dataclasses               0.8                pyh787bdff_0    conda-forge
    decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0
    defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
    diff-match-patch          20200713                   py_0
    distributed               2.20.0                   py36_0
    docutils                  0.16                     py36_1
    entrypoints               0.3                      py36_0
    et_xmlfile                1.0.1                   py_1001
    fastcache                 1.1.0            py36he774522_0
    filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0
    flake8                    3.8.3                      py_0
    flask                     1.1.2                      py_0
    freetype                  2.10.2               hd328e21_0
    fsspec                    0.7.4                      py_0
    future                    0.17.1                   pypi_0    pypi
    get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
    gevent                    1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    glob2                     0.7                        py_0
    gmpy2                     2.0.8            py36h0964b28_3
    greenlet                  0.4.16           py36he774522_0
    h5py                      2.10.0           py36h5e291fa_0
    hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
    heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0
    html5lib                  1.1                        py_0
    humanfriendly             9.2                      pypi_0    pypi
    hyperlink                 21.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
    icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
    idna                      2.10                       py_0
    imageio                   2.9.0                      py_0
    imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0
    immutables                0.14             py36he774522_0
    importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    py36_0
    importlib_metadata        1.7.0                         0
    incremental               21.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
    intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_1
    ipykernel                 5.3.2            py36h5ca1d4c_0
    ipython                   7.16.1           py36h5ca1d4c_0
    ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0
    ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0
    isort                     4.3.21                   py36_0
    itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py36_0
    jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0
    jedi                      0.17.1                   py36_0
    jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0
    jmespath                  0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    joblib                    0.16.0                     py_0
    jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
    json5                     0.9.5                      py_0
    jsonschema                2.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_7
    jupyter_client            6.1.6                      py_0
    jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0
    jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py36_0
    jupyterlab                2.1.5                      py_0
    jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0
    keyring                   21.2.1                   py36_0
    kiwisolver                1.2.0            py36h74a9793_0
    klein                     17.10.0                  pypi_0    pypi
    krb5                      1.18.2               hc04afaa_0
    lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py36he774522_0
    libarchive                3.4.2                h5e25573_0
    libcurl                   7.71.1               h2a8f88b_1
    libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
    liblief                   0.10.1               ha925a31_0
    libllvm9                  9.0.1                h21ff451_0
    libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
    libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
    libspatialindex           1.9.3                h33f27b4_0
    libssh2                   1.9.0                h7a1dbc1_1
    libtiff                   4.1.0                h56a325e_1
    libxml2                   2.9.10               h464c3ec_1
    libxslt                   1.1.34               he774522_0
    llvmlite                  0.33.0           py36ha925a31_0
    locket                    0.2.0            py36hfed976d_1
    lxml                      4.5.2            py36h1350720_0
    lz4-c                     1.9.2                h62dcd97_0
    lzo                       2.10                 he774522_2
    m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
    m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
    m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
    m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
    m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
    markupsafe                1.1.1            py36he774522_0
    matplotlib                2.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
    matplotlib-base           3.2.2            py36h64f37c6_0
    mccabe                    0.6.1                    py36_1
    menuinst                  1.4.16           py36he774522_1
    mistune                   0.8.4            py36he774522_0
    mkl                       2019.4                      245
    mkl-service               2.3.0            py36hb782905_0
    mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py36h6288b17_0
    mkl_random                1.0.4            py36h343c172_0
    mock                      4.0.2                      py_0
    more-itertools            8.4.0                      py_0
    mpc                       1.1.0                h7edee0f_1
    mpfr                      4.0.2                h62dcd97_1
    mpir                      3.0.0                hec2e145_1
    mpmath                    1.1.0                    py36_0
    msgpack-python            1.0.0            py36h74a9793_1
    msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
    multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py36_0
    murmurhash                1.0.5            py36he2d232f_0    conda-forge
    navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py36_0
    nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py36_0
    nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0
    networkx                  2.4                        py_1
    nltk                      3.5                        py_0  
    nose                      1.3.7                    py36_2
    notebook                  6.0.3                    py36_0
    numba                     0.50.1           py36h47e9c7a_0
    numexpr                   2.7.1            py36h25d0782_0
    numpy                     1.18.5                   pypi_0    pypi
    numpy-base                1.17.0           py36hc3f5095_0
    numpydoc                  1.1.0                      py_0
    olefile                   0.46                     py36_0
    openpyxl                  3.0.4                      py_0
    openssl                   1.1.1g               he774522_0    conda-forge
    packaging                 18.0                     pypi_0    pypi
    pandas                    1.0.5            py36h47e9c7a_0
    pandoc                    2.10                          0
    pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py36_1
    paramiko                  2.7.1                      py_0
    parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
    partd                     1.1.0                      py_0
    path                      13.1.0                   py36_0
    path.py                   12.4.0                        0
    pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py36_0
    pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1
    pathy                     0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
    patsy                     0.5.1                    py36_0
    pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0
    pexpect                   4.8.0                    py36_0
    pickleshare               0.7.5                    py36_0
    pillow                    7.2.0            py36hcc1f983_0
    pip                       20.1.1                   py36_1
    pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py36_0
    pluggy                    0.13.1                   py36_0
    ply                       3.11                     py36_0
    powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
    praw                      7.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    prawcore                  2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    preshed                   3.0.5            py36he2d232f_1    conda-forge
    prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0
    prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0
    prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                         0
    psutil                    5.7.0            py36he774522_0
    py                        1.9.0                      py_0
    py-lief                   0.10.1           py36ha925a31_0
    pycodestyle               2.6.0                      py_0
    pycosat                   0.6.3            py36he774522_0
    pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
    pycrypto                  2.6.1           py36he774522_10
    pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py36h7a1dbc1_0
    pydantic                  1.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
    pydocstyle                5.0.2                      py_0
    pyflakes                  2.2.0                      py_0
    pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0
    pylint                    2.5.3                    py36_0
    pynacl                    1.4.0            py36h62dcd97_1
    pyodbc                    4.0.30           py36ha925a31_0
    pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1
    pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0
    pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h6538335_2
    pyreadline                2.1                      py36_1
    pyrsistent                0.16.0           py36he774522_0
    pysocks                   1.7.1                    py36_0
    pytables                  3.6.1            py36h1da0976_0
    pytest                    5.4.3                    py36_0
    python                    3.6.10               h9f7ef89_2
    python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
    python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_1
    python-language-server    0.34.1                   py36_0
    python-libarchive-c       2.9                        py_0
    python_abi                3.6                     2_cp36m    conda-forge
    pytz                      2020.1                     py_0
    pywavelets                1.1.1            py36he774522_0
    pywin32                   227              py36he774522_1
    pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py36_1000
    pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py36_0
    pyyaml                    5.3.1            py36he774522_1
    pyzmq                     19.0.1           py36ha925a31_1
    qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0
    qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
    qtawesome                 0.7.2                      py_0
    qtconsole                 4.7.5                      py_0
    qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0
    rasa-nlu                  0.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
    regex                     2020.6.8         py36he774522_0
    requests                  2.24.0                     py_0
    rope                      0.17.0                     py_0
    rtree                     0.9.4            py36h21ff451_1
    ruamel-yaml               0.15.100                 pypi_0    pypi
    ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py36he774522_1
    s3transfer                0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    scikit-image              0.16.2           py36h47e9c7a_0
    scikit-learn              0.20.4                   pypi_0    pypi
    scipy                     1.5.0            py36h9439919_0
    seaborn                   0.10.1                     py_0
    send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0
    setuptools                49.2.0                   py36_0
    shellingham               1.4.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
    simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2
    simplejson                3.17.3                   pypi_0    pypi
    singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36h17d0c80_0
    sip                       4.19.8           py36h6538335_0
    six                       1.15.0                     py_0
    smart_open                5.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
    snappy                    1.1.8                h33f27b4_0
    snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0
    sortedcollections         1.2.1                      py_0
    sortedcontainers          2.2.2                      py_0
    soupsieve                 2.0.1                      py_0
    spacy                     3.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
    spacy-legacy              3.0.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
    sphinx                    3.1.2                      py_0
    sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py36_1
    sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0
    sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0
    sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                      py_0
    sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0
    sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0
    sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                      py_0
    sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.3                      py_0
    spyder                    4.1.4                    py36_0
    spyder-kernels            1.9.2                    py36_0
    sqlalchemy                1.3.18           py36he774522_0
    sqlite                    3.32.3               h2a8f88b_0
    srsly                     2.4.1            py36he2d232f_0    conda-forge
    statsmodels               0.11.1           py36he774522_0
    sympy                     1.6.1                    py36_0
    tbb                       2020.0               h74a9793_0
    tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0
    terminado                 0.8.3                    py36_0
    testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
    thinc                     8.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
    threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0
    tk                        8.6.10               he774522_0
    toml                      0.10.1                     py_0
    toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0
    tornado                   6.0.4            py36he774522_1
    tqdm                      4.47.0                     py_0
    traitlets                 4.3.3                    py36_0
    twisted                   21.7.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    twisted-iocpsupport       1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
    typed-ast                 1.4.1            py36he774522_0
    typer                     0.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
    typing                    3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
    typing-extensions         3.10.0.0                 pypi_0    pypi
    typing_extensions         3.7.4.2                    py_0
    ujson                     1.35             py36hfa6e2cd_0
    unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36h6450c06_0
    update-checker            0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    urllib3                   1.25.9                     py_0
    vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
    vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_3
    wasabi                    0.8.2              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
    watchdog                  0.10.3                   py36_0
    wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0
    webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1
    websocket-client          0.58.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0
    wheel                     0.34.2                   py36_0
    widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py36_0
    win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py36_0
    win_unicode_console       0.5              py36hcdbd4b5_0
    wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
    winpty                    0.4.3                         4
    wrapt                     1.11.2           py36he774522_0
    xlrd                      1.2.0                    py36_0
    xlsxwriter                1.2.9                      py_0
    xlwings                   0.19.5                   py36_0
    xlwt                      1.3.0            py36h1a4751e_0
    xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0
    xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
    yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
    yapf                      0.30.0                     py_0
    zeromq                    4.3.2                ha925a31_2
    zict                      2.0.0                      py_0
    zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0
    zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
    zope                      1.0                      py36_1
    zope.event                4.4                      py36_0
    zope.interface            4.7.1            py36he774522_0
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, they're hard to read and unhelpful.

Comment: This is a very old version of rasa, rasa-nlu and rasa-core were merged in 2019. Any reason why you're not using a more recent version of rasa?

In any case, have you tried linking the model?  ```python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en```